# Traduction de " framework propriétaire "

Tags: expressions, informatique

Bonjour

Dans le cadre d'une mise à jour d'un CV, je m'interrogeais sur la traduction de Framework propriétaire.

Serait-ce  "Proprietary framework" ? Ca sonne comme un faux ami.

Merci beaucoup

Comment: Et pourtant c'est correct :)

Comment: Oui, c'est correct.  (*proprietary software*  en général, et *proprietary framework* pour votre cas)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about French.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Sorry @StéphaneGimenez if I was mistaken using this part of StackExchange :) But for me it was clear I could use it as I needed a translation from french to english to be sure I was right (expression Proprietary framework) But in such a case, you should purpose to move this topic and not close it in any way. That's not nice